# How to setup connection between a unix server installed on windows machine and a ms sql server installed in windows machine

Tags: windows, unix, sql-server-2012, odbc, tcp

I would like to know the
1. steps involved in setting up the connection between a UNIX server installed on windows machine and a SQL server 2012 installed in an another windows machine (remotely).
2. How to test the connectivity is established or not from UNIX server.

Thanks,

Comment: This question is not suited for SO, as written. Also... What is a "UNIX server installed on windows"? UNIX and Windows are peer-level operating systems. SQL Server is a DBMS, which runs on Windows. There are many data consuming applications which might run on UNIX, Windows, and other OS. What have you done so far? With what results?

Answer (score 0):

Not much information what you have done so far...

Steps required:

1. Install UnixOdbc: http://www.unixodbc.org/
2. Install Microsoft ODBC Driver for Linux: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx
3. Configure UnixOdbc to use the Microsoft ODBC Driver.
4. use `isql` which is part of unixodbc to test the connectivity.